# UITableViewCell displaying custom labels and images duplicate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image: New image added]**Image still shows cells top and bottom**

[image: Screen shot]

I'm using indexPath.row to determine the type of image and label to display but unfortunately it displays at the top and also very bottom of the table too thereby duplicating cells below is my code:

import Foundation
import UIKit

```
//custom cell
```

class menuTableCells: UITableViewCell{

```
var menuName: String?
var menuIcon: UIImage?

var lblMenuName: UILabel = {
    let view = UILabel()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

var menuImage: UIImageView = {
    let view = UIImageView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.addSubview(lblMenuName)
    self.addSubview(menuImage)

    //constraints for icons
    menuImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    menuImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    menuImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
    menuImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true

    //constraints for label menu
    lblMenuName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menuImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    lblMenuName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    lblMenuName.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    if let menuName = menuName{
        lblMenuName.text = menuName
    }

    if let menuIcon = menuIcon {
        menuImage.image = menuIcon
    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

```
//struct to hold data
struct MenuCellData {
let menuName: String?
let menuIcon: UIImage?
```

}

```
class SidebarView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

var titleArr = [String]()
var iconsArr = [String]()
var populateData = [MenuCellData]()

weak var delegate: SidebarViewDelegate?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.80)
    self.clipsToBounds = true

    titleArr = ["Home", "The Prophet", "Devotions", "Church Events", "Ahofadiekrom", "Branches", "Gallery", "Videos", "Live Streaming", "Live Radio", "Elijah TV", "Contact Us"]
    iconsArr = ["home-1", "devotion", "devotion", "events", "worship", "branches", "gallery", "videos", "live", "radio", "logo1", "contact"]



    setUpViews()

    myTableView.delegate = self
    myTableView.dataSource = self
    myTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    myTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    myTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
    myTableView.allowsSelection = true
    myTableView.bounces = false
    myTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    myTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return populateData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! menuTableCells
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    let menus = MenuCellData(menuName: titleArr[indexPath.row], menuIcon: UIImage(named: iconsArr[indexPath.row]))
    populateData.append(menus)
    myTableView.reloadData()

    cell.menuName = populateData[indexPath.row].menuName
    cell.menuIcon = populateData[indexPath.row].menuIcon


    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.delegate?.sidebarDidSelectRow(row: Row(row: indexPath.row))


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}

let appLogo: UIImageView = {
    let view = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "logo"))
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

let myTableView: UITableView = {
    let table = UITableView()
    table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return table
}()


func setUpViews(){
    self.addSubview(appLogo)
    appLogo.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    appLogo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    appLogo.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    appLogo.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

    self.addSubview(myTableView)
    myTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    myTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: appLogo.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    myTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    myTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Comment: you way is wrong.. you are using resusable cells and using indexpath.row wrongly... instead of using this just indexpath inside your cell

Comment: Why are you adding label and UIImageView in this method? Since you are reusing cells, after multiple reuses each cell will have a lot of labels and image views. You already have a storyboard with a cell in it. So just add Label And Image View on the storyboard cell and just set the values in this method.

Comment: You have a lot of redundant code which like @ShauketSheikh said can be reduced if you use reusable cells.

Comment: create a custom tableview cell class, and setup data inside that also set your indexpath in custom cell, and whenever you want to use in your viewcontroller just check the cell indexpath is this then setup data according to that...

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I'm not using a storyboard.

Comment: @chevi99 you don't need to either.

Comment: @ShauketSheikh can you pls share a sample code?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding `UIImage` and `UILable` at run time try using custom cell. For more details about how to use custom and default cell please follow this tutorial [Here](https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath)

        let headline = headlines[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = headline.title
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: headline.image)

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code and i get this error "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'subviews' is a get-only property" in the else block at cell.subviews.removeAll()

Comment: i have updated answer, please check updated answer and let me know if you need more details

Comment: Error is no more but it is still duplicating cells top and bottom

Comment: I have added the respective images

Comment: I will add more details tomorrow

Comment: Okay will be waiting for your assistance

Comment: ok thanks but my worry now is the image how can I write constraints for it because  it looks very big

Comment: please share screenshot

Comment: So i created another array for the images like titleArr = ["Home", "The Prophet", "Devotions", "Church Events", "Ahofadiekrom", "Branches", "Gallery", "Videos", "Live Streaming", "Live Radio", "Elijah TV", "Contact Us"] // Array for the label
        iconsArr = ["home-1", "devotion", "devotion", "events", "worship", "branches", "gallery", "videos", "live", "radio", "logo1", "contact"] // Array for the images. So to display them i did this let headline = titleArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = headline
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: iconsArr[indexPath.row])

Comment: create custom cell

Comment: I have edited my code I just created a custom cell as you directed but the table doesn't populate any data

Answer (score 0):

```
//My custom class table cells
import Foundation
```

import UIKit

class menuTableCells: UITableViewCell{

```
var menuName: String?
var menuIcon: UIImage?

var lblMenuName: UILabel = {
    let view = UILabel()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

var menuImage: UIImageView = {
    let view = UIImageView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.addSubview(lblMenuName)
    self.addSubview(menuImage)

    //constraints for icons
    menuImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    menuImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    menuImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
    menuImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true


    //constraints for label menu
    lblMenuName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.menuImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    lblMenuName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
```

//        lblMenuName.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        lblMenuName.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        lblMenuName.textColor = .white

```
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    if let menuName = menuName{
        lblMenuName.text = menuName
    }

    if let menuIcon = menuIcon {
        menuImage.image = menuIcon
    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

```
//Struct variables
struct MenuCellData {
let menuName: String?
let menuIcon: UIImage?
```

}

```
var populateData = [MenuCellData]()
//populated my array with menu items
populateData = [MenuCellData.init(menuName: "Home", menuIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "home-1")), MenuCellData.init(menuName: "The Prophet", menuIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "devotion")), MenuCellData.init(menuName: "Devotions", menuIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "devotion")), MenuCellData.init(menuName: "Church Events", menuIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "events")), MenuCellData.init(menuName: "Ahofadiekrom", menuIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "worship")), MenuCellData.init(menuName: "Branches", menuIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "branches")), MenuCellData.init(menuName: "Gallery", menuIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "gallery")), MenuCellData.init(menuName: "Videos", menuIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "videos")), MenuCellData.init(menuName: "Live Streaming", menuIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "live")), MenuCellData.init(menuName: "Live Radio", menuIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "radio")), MenuCellData.init(menuName: "Elijah TV", menuIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "logo1")), MenuCellData.init(menuName: "Contact Us", menuIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "contact"))]
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return populateData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! menuTableCells
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.selectionStyle = .none



    cell.menuName = populateData[indexPath.row].menuName
    cell.menuIcon = populateData[indexPath.row].menuIcon


    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.delegate?.sidebarDidSelectRow(row: Row(row: indexPath.row))


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}
```

Viola!!!